# How to pen c drive in windows using html or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to open c drive using html and javascript on windows not on browser

This is the code which open c drive in browser

```
<a target="_blank" href="file://c:\">useful link </a>
```

but i want it open in the windows like we normally open the c drive using html or javascript

Comment: You can't open files in the C:\ drive through a document for the reason that your computer is not a server.

Comment: If you could do that, it would be a serious security vulnerability.

Comment: @user3721246 do you need help with something else? Or can you accept my answer?

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell").Run('"c:\"');
```

if you're looking for a full blown app on windows using `html` and `JavaScript`, check out HTA: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536495(v=vs.85).aspx

example HTA:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Test</title>

    <HTA:APPLICATION
      border="thin"
      borderStyle="normal"
      caption="yes"
      contextMenu="no"
      innerBorder="yes"
      maximizeButton="yes"
      minimizeButton="yes"
      navigable="yes"
      scroll="auto"
      scrollFlat="yes"
      showInTaskbar="yes"
      sysmenu="yes"
      windowState="normal"
    />

    <script>
      function openCDrive() {
        new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell").Run('"c:\"');
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body class="bodyMain">
    <a href="#" onclick="openCDrive();">Open C Drive</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

save above as test.hta and launch it...